# I need PHP function like wise yearfrac(date1,date2) in excel

Tags: php, excel, date

I need PHP function like wise `yearfrac(date1,date2)` in excel formula.

Currently I am using below code for getting age from two different dates.

```
$interval = date_diff(date_create($date1),date_create($date2));
$age = $interval->format("%Y");
```

It gives max value, that means if answer is 5.6 then it gives 6.

In excel, it returns 5.6.

Comment: what does yearfrac in excel do specifically?

Comment: date1 = 22-Oct-1993
date2 = 25-Apr-2016
yearfrac(date1,date2) = 22.50833333

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work as per your requirement:

```
$date1 = new DateTime("1966-05-21");
$date2 = new DateTime("1969-04-23");


$diff = $date1->diff($date2);

echo round(($diff->days/365),1);
```

Comment: above is example is for the dates before 1970. And this is working

Comment: your answer is not correct for all inputs, please see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer is not really correct. For dates 2012-01-01 and 2012-07-30 you are getting:

- `0.57808219178082` in above PHP version (Without rounding)
- `0.58055555555556` in Excel

You can find the correct implementation of this function in `PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet` package, see: https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet/blob/83a50537b200a9942ea593863f04fa1bb77b388a/src/PhpSpreadsheet/Calculation/DateTime.php#L897